# Two LEFT JOIN's in single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to insert the "title" from two different tables in a MySql query. If I try the first query below, it works. Once I add the second `LEFT JOIN`, it still gets the first, 'blog' title, but doesn't pick up the second, 'albums' title. Any ideas on how to get both titles from both tables? Note that I need to make sure I have both those conditions in there for each: `updates.ref_table = 'albums' AND updates.ref_id = albums.id`

Works...

```
$query = "SELECT updates.*, albums.title FROM updates ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN albums ON updates.ref_table = 'albums' AND updates.ref_id = albums.id ";
$query .= "WHERE user_id = ".$user_id." ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Doen't work...

```
$query = "SELECT updates.*, albums.title, blog.title FROM updates ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN blog ON updates.ref_table = 'blog' AND updates.ref_id = blog.id ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN albums ON updates.ref_table = 'albums' AND updates.ref_id = albums.id ";
$query .= "WHERE user_id = ".$user_id." ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one column in the result with the same name you will only get the one result, so rename the columns with the same name and you will get them all and also they will have a meaningful name so you know which one is which.

```
$query = "SELECT updates.*, albums.title as albumtitle, blog.title as blogtitle FROM updates ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN blog ON updates.ref_table = 'blog' AND updates.ref_id = blog.id ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN albums ON updates.ref_table = 'albums' AND updates.ref_id = albums.id ";
$query .= "WHERE user_id = ".$user_id." ORDER BY date DESC";
```